# Create SCO client profile driver for call control from Bluetooth headset

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth, wdk, hfp

**Overview**

Hi everyone, I'm developing a feature for a Softphone (run on windows), that's make answer/end a call from Bluetooth headsets or speakerphones. I have read and do step by step follow Hands-free Profile spec: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/hands-free-profile-1-8/

Currently, I have set up "Sevice Level Connection" by send/recv AT commands follow the spec.

**Problem**

1. I don't know how to set-up Audio Connection that know as **SCO connection**. It's seem need to write a custom driver, that I have no experience with. The only tutorial I see from Microsoft is very difficult to understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/creating-a-sco-client-connection-to-a-remote-device
2. Is there any way to bypass this step without code a driver?
3. If I can set-up Audio Connection then Can I answer/end call from Bluetooth headset?

This is Initialization Sevice Level Connection diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KMlb.png

This is Answer Call diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8WZf.png

Comment: 1. Learn how to develop drivers (KMDF is what you need). 2. Yes and no, depends on your requirements. 3. Yes. Expanded 2: use standard windows My Phone application. It installs HFP driver that can be simple used then by yoyr application.

Comment: Thanks @MikePetrichenko, your mean is Phone Link app?https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NMPJ99VJBWV?

Comment: (1) I know it depend on my skill, but as a beginner, how long I need to spent learning how to develop this driver?

Comment: Sorry, the app called "Your phone" It is standard Win 10 app that is preinstalled with Windows. There is no answer on this question. It may take 1 year, or 10 years. I do not think that it may take less than 3 months.

Comment: Thanks @MikePetrichenko. But I don't understand how to use HFP driver on YouR Phone app? Could you describe more detail about it, please?

Comment: Discover Bluetooth devices to find your one. Enumerate its services. Find service you need (HandsFree Audio Gateway) and then install it by using BluetoothSetServiceState. Once device installed you can use new audio device. You have to use RfComm control channel to control the HandsFree and send commands to it separately.

Comment: I see this site say: "Windows 10 (Version 1903) supports HFP", so what is level it support? 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/supported-bluetooth-profiles-8900e50f-318e-4283-2beb-c8325bfc9515

Comment: @MikePetrichenko,  I have performed all step you say, but which is the step relevant to HFP driver of Your Phone app or SCO driver? This is my code: bit.ly/3xBtNGg

Comment: Default Win10 driver (without my Phone app) supports only HandsFree Profile. If you want to connect to phone (PC appears as HandsFree Gateway) you need the My Phone app.

Comment: I took a look on your code but I have no idea what third party classes you use so I can't help with that.

Comment: I used 32Feet .NET

Comment: No, I want to connect PC and Headset, not phone

Comment: Are you mean I should connect PC to Your Phone, then connect phone to headset?

Comment: No, you can simple connect to HFP service control channel after installing the driver. About 32feet its better to contact 32feet support. I can help with native API calls or with our products only.

Comment: Yes, then I have to write SCO profile driver for SCO connection? or just init Sevice Level Connection then it's possible answer call from headset?

Comment: You do not need custom profile driver for HFP profile. It is shipped with Windows 10 (and, AFAIR, Win 8)

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance, I will retry with native API

Comment: Hi @MikePetrichenko, currently I can accept/reject/end call by send/recv AT commands (I use C# with System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime) but I must disable Handsfree Telephony service from window (https://ibb.co/VSDTXnh), and this not only made microphone on Bluetooth headset not work but also made my softphone can't find recording device. If I enable Handsfree Telephony service, rfcomm socket will could't connect to handsfree telephony service.

Comment: It throw error: "Could not connect to service Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."

Comment: It apears because you paired your device from Windows UI. It installs all the services. You should pair it from the app using BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx or similar. (Do not forget to disable Authentication Agent, otherwise pairing will be handled by the system). After that you have to install required services (HandsFree one) by using BluetoothSetServiceState for Hands Free Audio so the system installs only required service without touching control channel. Next you have to connect to control channel and follow the HFP protocol answer on all initialization commands.

Comment: How to I can disable Authentication Agent? I don't see it in BlutoothAPI of WinAPI

Comment: There is no API. However there is undocummented method. Unfortunately I can not share that information. Try to find the way by yourself.

Comment: Does your btframework have this?

Comment: Yes it includes all the things.

Comment: I tried with your framework demo, but recording devices on window still not display my device (https://ibb.co/GVXVNkr) ?

Comment: As I wrote you have to install device for HFP service.

Comment: I am preparing the simple demo app. It may take some time so I'll let you know when finish.

Comment: Here I created a very simple demo that shows how to connect to HandsFree device with Audio and control channel: https://github.com/btframework/HandsFreeConnect

Comment: Thanks @MikePetrichenko, it can connect to my device (ColumnHeader: true, Connected: true), but it throw this error: https://ibb.co/JyR6HLY

Comment: Make sure that device is completely removed before connecting.

Comment: I surely removed it before connecting. I use "Remove device" button to remove (https://ibb.co/cwmz63j). Is there any place that I haven't removed yet?

Comment: Then there are 2 possible problem with your device: 1. There is some third party driver/app installed on your PC that handles the connection. 2. Your device should use other than HFP service. I tested with Jabra BT2045

Comment: It also get similar error with Galaxy Buds Pro, but this err don't happend on RFCOMM client demo

Comment: It looks like your system hooks control channel instead of leaving it not connected. I'll look for other solution. Better if you contact our support by e-mail or other way instead of discussing all the things here.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my findings and solution after fighting for it for several days. Probably more adequate for the reverse engineering stackexchange but anyway...

I must say I am more and more "impressed" lately with Microsoft's technical decisions. And the Bluetooth Hands-free is adding points to the above.

The Hands-free profile is available for quite some time/years now and when Microsoft finally got it natively under Windows there's no public API to work with.
And like the OP I want to use my BT Handsfree (Plantronics PLT70 if it matters) with all of its functions in my implementation of a SIP Softphone.

- The following applies to the Microsoft Bluetooth Stack. Tested under Win10 21H2 (19044.3086);
- The device should be normally paired to Windows;
- One must have the "Handsfree Telephony" service checked ON in the Device Properties -> Services tab;
- One must have the "Bluetooth Audio Gateway Service" / BTAGService stopped (and probably disabled to keep it stopped upon bluetooth radio being plugged in).

**Part 1**
Open a device driver handle to the Hands-free service instance exposed by the bthenum driver for your handsfree device. I will not go into details on how to find the device path but one could figure it or probably use SetupApi/Registry to find it. The code will look like this (Delphi style, version 5 if it matters):

```
hBthf := CreateFile('\\?\BTHENUM#{0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&0001000f_PID&0000#8&F070F74&0&48C1ACF774C4_C00000000#{bd41df2d-addd-4fc9-a194-b9881d2a2efa}\service',
    GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
```

48C1ACF774C4 from the path is my device MAC address.
The FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED is needed as one has to make simultaneous requests to the driver.

Spin a thread that will continuously send the 0x2A0024 IOCTL (not documented, hence reverse engineering) with an output buffer of 4 bytes to the device driver handle. On this thread the driver will notify you and will make requests whenever one tries to access the audio channel of the Hands-free using the Multimedia API - i.e. any app trying to record/play on it; in my case the playback audio channel is named as "Headset (PLT_M70 Hands-Free AG Audio)". The nofify/request code will be in the 4 byte buffer (a DWORD/INT) once the IOCTL completes.

```
...
var
  ol: TOverlapped;
  request: Integer;
  br: Cardinal;
...
DeviceIoControl(hBthf, $2A0024, nil, 0, @request, 4, br, @ol)
```

The "requests" one needs to answer are 4, 5 and 6. I suspect the other codes are notifications (1 is probably for SCO channel up, 2 for SCO channel down, 0 something else?). The reply is sent back to the driver with IOCTL code 0x2A0028 and an eight byte input buffer. The contents of the buffer are: a DWORD with the request code, that one is replying to, and then another byte with 0x01 and another with 0x02 and then two zero bytes. I'm not sure (yet?) what the meaning of these bytes is. I tried with different values with 1-1, 3-3 and it seems as if (doubtedly) they do not matter. Code:

```
...
var
  b: array of byte;
...
SetLength(b, 8);
...
if (request = 4) or (request = 6) then
begin
  PDWORD(@b[0])^ := request;
  PDWORD(@b[4])^ := $0201;
  DeviceIoControl(hBthf, $2A0028, @b[0], 8, nil, 0, br, @ol);
end;
```

**Part 2**
The other part of the solution is to be integrated into the AT command chat on the RFCOMM channel the OP has already worked out. Once the Service Level Connection is established one has to issue these IOCTLs to the driver:

```
// Service Level Connection status
// -> 0x2A0004, inBuffer = 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x9B 0x00 0x00 0x00

// -> 0x2A0020, null input, null output

// Set codec
// -> 0x2A0014, inBuffer 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 (DWORD Codec ID 1 or 2)
```

After the above "magic" IOCTLs the Hands-free Audio Gateway device will be "discovered" and made available in Windows for apps to play/record with.

A final note: without the request handler thread in the first part of the solution the device will still appear in Windows, however any app trying to use it will hang. The solution to "unhang" it is to remove the radio (provided it is a removable USB dongle). Not sure whether "disable"/"enable" from Device Manager would work.